# How should I link a data Class to my GUI code (to display attributes of object, in C++)?

Tags: c++, database, qt, visualization, boost-graph

I have a class (in C++), call it `Data`, that has thousands of instances (objects) when the code is run. I have a widget (in Qt), call it `DataWidget` that displays attributes of the objects. To rapidly build the widget I simply wrote the object attributes to a file and had the widget parse the file for the attributes - this approach works, but isn't scalable or pretty.

To be more clear my requirements are:
*1* - `DataWidget` should be able to display multiple, different, `Data` object's attributes at a time
*2* - `DataWidget` should be able to display thousands of `Data` objects per second
*3* - `DataWidget` should be run along side the code that generates new `Data` objects
*4* - each `Data` object needs to be permanently saved to file/database

Currently, the GUI is created and the `DataWidget` is created then the experiment runs and generates thousands of `Data` objects (periodically writing some of them to file). After the experiment runs the `DataWidget` displays the last `Data` object written to file (they are written to XML files).

With my current file approach I can satisfy *(1)* by grabbing more than one file after the experiment runs. Since the experiment isn't tied to `DataWidget`, there is no concurrency, so I can't do *(3)* until I add a signal that informs the `DataWidget` that a new file exists.

I haven't moved forward with this approach for 2 reasons:
Firstly, even though the files aren't immediately written to disk, I can't imagine that this method is scalable unless *I* implement a caching system - but, this seems like I'm reinvent the wheel? Secondly, `Data` is a wrapper for a graph data-structure and I'm using Graphml (via Boost Graph Library i.e. *write_graphml()*) to write the structure to XML files, and to read the structure back in with  Boost's *read_graphml()* requires me to read the file back into a `Data` object ... which means the experiment portion of the program encodes the object into XML, writes the XML to a file (but hopefully in memory and not to disk), then the `DataWidget` reads the XML from a file and decodes it into an object!

It seems to me like I should be using a database which would handle all the caching etc. Moreover, it seems like I should be able to skip the file/database step and pass the `Data` to the `DataWidget` in the program (perhaps pass it a reference to a list of `Data`). Yet, I also want to save the `Data` to file to the file/database step isn't entirely pointless - I'm just using it in the wrong way at the wrong time.

What is the better approach given my requirements?

Are there any general resources and/or guidelines for handling and displaying data like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using Qt.  This is good because Qt 4.0 and later includes a powerful model/view framework.  And I think this is what you want.

[Model/View](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/model-view-programming.html)

Basically, have your `Data` class inherit and implement QAbstractItemModel, or a different  Qt Model class, depending on the kind of model you want.  Then set your view widget (most likely a QListView) to use `Data` for its model.

There are lots of examples at their site and this solution scales nicely with large data sets.

Added: This model test code from labs.trolltech.com comes in real handy:

http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Itemview/Modeltest

Comment: Perfect, this also answers my concern of how do I uncouple the Data and DataWidget classes!

Comment: Great, I added a link to the modeltest code that is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me like I should be using
>   a database which would handle all the
>   caching etc. Moreover, it seems like I
>   should be able to skip the
>   file/database step and pass the Data
>   to the DataWidget in the program
>   (perhaps pass it a reference to a list
>   of Data). Yet, I also want to save the
>   Data to file to the file/database step
>   isn't entirely pointless - I'm just
>   using it in the wrong way at the wrong
>   time.

If you need to display that much rapidly changing data, having an intermediate file or database will slow it down and likely become the bottleneck. I think the Widget should read the newly generated data directly from memory. This doesn't prevent you from storing the data in a file or database though, it can be done in a separate thread/process.

Comment: How do I couple the classes so that the Widget class can access the Data properties? Do I inherit the Widget from the Data?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the data items will fit in memory, I'd say put them in a vector/list, and pass a reference to that to the DataWidget. When it's time to save them, pass a reference to your serializing method. Then your experiment just populates the data structure for the other processes to use.